# Cannot Repaint in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a Calendar using Java that displays the current month when opened and then when the buttons are pressed will show either the previous or next month. It seems as though the underlying code is correct, as I am able to see the month changing in the command line, but nothing changes in the Frame. I believe this is due to how my ActionListener is implemented, but I have tried a few other ways (some can be seen commented out) and nothing seems to do the trick.

This is my full code, any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CalendarHack extends JPanel {
  SimpleDateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
  SimpleDateFormat year = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
  SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
  Date date = new Date();

  private static JButton back = new JButton("Back");
  private static JButton next = new JButton("Next");

  public CalendarHack()
  {

  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(month.format(date), 110, 36);
    g.drawString(year.format(date), 310, 36);

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.setTime(date);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 1);
    String days = "Sun           Mon            Tue           Wed          Thur          Fri             Sat";
    g.drawString(days,50, 90);
    g.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 40));

    for (int week = 0; week < 6; week++) {
      for (int d = 0; d < 7; d++) {
        if(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == today.get(Calendar.MONTH))
        {
            g.drawString(day.format(cal.getTime()) , d * 30  + 50 + ((25 * d)) , week * 29 + 81 + 20 + 30 + (week * 10) );
        }
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
      }
    }
  }

  public void paint()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.setTitle("Event Calendar");
    CalendarHack ch = new CalendarHack();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(135, 350, 200, 200);

    ActionListener monthListen = new MonthListener();
//    back.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
//    {
//        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
//        {
//          Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
//          c.setTime(date);
//          c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
//          date = c.getTime();
//          System.out.println("Repainting...");
//          repaint();
//          System.out.println(date.toString());
//        }
//    });
    back.addActionListener(monthListen);
    next.addActionListener(monthListen);
    panel.add(back);
    panel.add(next);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(ch);
    //frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
        CalendarHack cal = new CalendarHack();
        cal.paint();
  }


class MonthListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == back)
            {
              Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
              c.setTime(date);
              c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
              date = c.getTime();
              repaint();
              System.out.println(date.toString());
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == next)
            {
              Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
              c.setTime(date);
              c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
              date = c.getTime();
              repaint();
              System.out.println(date.toString());
            }
            //CalendarHack.repaint();
            repaint();
        }
    }      

}
```

Comment: How is what you're doing in you `ActionListener` related to, well, anything?  You define all the variables as local...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Actually, the OP just named a method `paint` - and yes, it freaked me out to...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: you're right, my bad. It does not conform to the `paint(Graphics g)` method. Sigh, time to go to bed.

Comment: Will it be ok if I just change paint() to init() and call that instead? I did that because I originally had that code in my Main method but that was causing issues due to non-static methods and objects being called in it.

Comment: Yes, `paint` freaks a few of us out as it's used as part of the painting framework ;)

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: I've changed that just to not alarm anyone in the future. I just saw your original question, what I'm trying to do in `ActionListener` is either move `date` back or forward 1 month. `date` should be a public variable and once that has been changed I'm trying to `repaint()` which I think will run paintComponent again with the new date resulting in a different month being drawn.